# CSRF Protection: Hashed PHPSESSID enough?

Tags: php, security, xss, csrf

Just wondering if requiring a hashed PHPSESSID to be sent to all forms or action scripts is enough for CSRF protection?  I understand this can be obtained if the user's are on the same physical network (firesheep).  Example:

http://site.com/deleteMessage.php?mid=22&token=MD5ed_PHPSESSID

Disregarding the same network issue the PHPSESSID:

```
 1) Is known only to the user doing the action
 2) Can not be guessed by an attacker crafting a malicious img or request (<img src="http://site.com/deleteMessage.php?mid=22&token=I_DONT_KNOW_IT_:( )
 3) Can not be pulled on the same site assuming no XSS vulnerabilities exist.
 4) Can easily be pulled by the legitimate user (Javascript fills the form or GET var in the link)
```

Number 3 worries me, although I don't have any XSS vulnerabilities that I'm aware of, as I htmlentities($string,ENT_QUOTES)ed everything, I do not like relying on assumptions.  Is this sufficient CSRF protection or is there a better way?

Comment: To avoid attacks like Firesheep, you should force HTTPS for anything that you'd want authenticated sessions for.

Comment: @Lèse majesté  thats true,  but this has nothing to do with his question.  Maybe you should talk to stackoverflow about their use of https (or lack there of).

Comment: @Rook: It's not an answer to the question (hence why I made a comment), but he does specifically mention the potential of Firesheep capturing his CSRF token if used on an insecure network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should use a token that is independent from the session ID. Just think of the case where an attacking site is able to obtain the victim’s session ID somehow (cf. [session fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) and [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack)) but isn’t able to use the session itself due to some additional session protection measures. Then it would still be possible to forge authentic requests as the token can be derived from the known session ID.

Just use a random token as everyone suggests.

Comment: If  the attacker has the session id then he has the keys to the kingdom.  He doesn't have to resort to CSRF because he has something much better. He can load a page and read the CSRF token right out of the form,  or just submit the form with his browser.  Chicken or the egg.

Comment: @Rook No, that does not have to be true in every case. Just think of other session protection measures that make it if not impossible at least harder to use that session directly.

Comment: the only case would be linking the IP address to the session id.  But that has its own problems.  There is no other form of protection or other condition,  period.

Comment: @Rook The IP address is one example, a client certificate another. And there might be other conditions unknown to the attacking site that can make it harder to use the session directly.

Answer (score 3):

If the attacker knows the session id then he doesn't have to use CSRF to influence the victim's session.  Its bad practice to use the hashed session id,  but it is not a vulnerability.   You could even use the session id its self and its technically not vulnerable to CSRF.  But it increases the likelihood of failure and preventing this failure is free.  Another cryptographic nonce is easy to generate.

XSS breaks every protection method on the [CSRF prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) except the use of a capthca.  That being said, you should protect your session id from XSS by using the HTTP_Only cookie flag.

Keep in mind that the HTTP_only flag **DOES NOT PREVENT XSS!**,  it just makes it more difficult to exploit.  Often times the attacker resorts to using XHR to read a CSRF token to "ride" on the session instead of hijacking the session id.

Comment: If it's not a vulnerability, then why do you consider using the hashed session ID bad practice?

Comment: @Lèse majesté  look at gumbo's comments.  It can undermine other exotic security systems.  Also,  another cryptographic nonce is free.

Comment: @Rook: I fail to understand how hashed CSRF could increase the likelihood of failure (assuming cryptographically safe hash is used). Could you elaborate a bit more? All attack scenarios I can think of allow avoiding CSRF protection if attacker is able to capture the session.

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen using a hashed session id as the CSRF token just strikes me as a bad design.  These should be independent variables.  I think gumbo has a better answer in this case.

Comment: @Rook: claiming that something is "a bad design" without explaining even a single theoretical problem looks like cargo cult design/programming to me. I understand that making CSRF token independent from session id is obviously safe. However, I see absolutely no reason to claim that making CSRF token dependant on session id would be unsafe. I'd like to be pointed incorrect...

Comment: @Mikko Rantalainen Gumbo's answer involves session fixation.  It is trivial,  absolutely trivial to generate an independent nonce.  So why not?

Comment: @Rook: The changes of somebody implementing a system vulnerable to session fixation and still even thinking about CSRF are pretty close to zero. I agree that *if* the system were able to create independent CSRF token despite the other failures, it might help in some corner case. However, the attacker could simply `GET` any form containing the independent CSRF token because he knows the session id.

Comment: My point is that **if your session id is exposed, no CSRF token of any kind can protect you** because the attacker can fetch the CSRF token using the session id.

Comment: By the way, if you use session id independent CSRF token, be sure to correctly validate it. See my answer for the question for details.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to protect against CSRF is to add a random hash to the session whenever you load a page with a form on it that you want to protect. Add that value to the form so that when a user submits it comes along for the ride. Match it to the session value on the other end.

Regenerate this random value every time the form is shown.

This works because if the user leaves and comes back, moves to a new form, whatever, the form will always match the last value created, which will in turn be the same one you check.

What you suggest might help, but is still vulnerable in the ways you mentioned. Why allow any vulnerability?

Comment: The user on the same network can always intercept the random value though as well as the session.  Off network XSS on the page would be able to grab the random value from the form and submit it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: This is why you change it every time the user loads a form. Stealing the session can be prevented by using SSL(https), which you should be doing. The rule with security is to make it as hard as possible, even if one defense is breached, don't give up the whole game.

Comment: While building your random token, in case of any md5() use (and not only), add some salt to it.

Comment: @Ronan Salt is not needed. Since you are using a random number in the hash, it essentially is all salt and will be random enough already.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Robust Defenses for Cross-Site Request Forgery by Barth, Jackson and Mitchell](http://seclab.stanford.edu/websec/csrf/csrf.pdf) it seems that HMAC of session identifier is the best generic solution.

According to that paper, session independent nonce that is not matched with session id in the server's state storage is vulnerable to active network attacks even when using TLS/SSL/HTTPS. HMAC of session identifier does not have similar vulnerability. Session independent nonce is okay as long as you match the nonce with the session id on the server instead of mathing `POST` parameters with `Cookie` header.

Comment: an hmac is significantly better than a straight hash,  but i would still just use /dev/urandom because an hmac can be brute-forced offline.

Comment: @Rook: are you really claiming that brute-forcing HMAC-SHA1 (assuming that the key has at least 128 bits of entropy) is a real threat?

Answer (score 0):

Use a token other than a hashed PHPSESSID, and then store the token in the session.  Also, the token should only be valid for a single submission.

Comment: You should change it every time. Especially if your pages aren't delivered by SSL. (which they should be!)

Comment: No no you shouldn't, not unless you want to break tabbed browsing for everyone and restrict them to only opening your site in a single tab.

Comment: @blowdart: Why would using single-use tokens break tabbed browsing? If you keep track of more than one token, you can still make them single use and not interfere with multiple tabs.

Comment: Well the classic way for CSRF mitigation is to have a token in the form, and in the cookie. You don't touch sessions, because sessions break over multiple hosts and they time out. Once you switch to regenerating canaries on every request the cookie gets overwritten, and then multiple tab support goes out the window. Using the session to hold things is generally considered unsafe, what with session hijacking etc.

Comment: @blowdart: That doesn't make any sense to me. The whole purpose of having HTTP sessions is to tie data to a particular session. If you don't use your session to hold session-specific data, then where would you store the true canary value? If you store it in a cookie only, how would you verify requests with it? Secondly, if they've already hijacked your session, then they don't really need CSRF. Lastly, even if you were using cookies to store your true canary value, there's no reason you can't store more than one canary value in a single cookie or use multiple cookies.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: if you accept only the latest token, you break tabbed browsing. On the other hand, if you accept any granted token, your security is in fact worse than using just single session-static token. The only reason to change the token is if you intentionally want to break opening multiple forms at once.

Comment: @Mikko: How would it be worse than a single session-static token if each form gets its own unique single-use token?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: if you keep granting more tokens, the changes for attacker to brute force a token is higher because there're now more possible values. However, if you are not using TLS/SSL there's no point because the attacker can simply get session id and then fetch as many new CSRF tokens as he wish.

Comment: @Mikko: For any non-trivial key space, it's going to be much harder for an attacker to guess the correct token matching each form, for every single form request, than it is for the attacker to figure out a static key that can be used for all requests on any form. And for any non-trivial key space, it would be impractical/impossible to brute force the token whether they have to match 1 key to any form or do that 20 times for 20 different forms.

Lastly, if the attacker can already hijack your session at will, why would they bother with an indirect CSRF attack?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: assuming any non-trivial key space for CSRF token, it really does not matter if you change token for each session or once for each request. You still need secure transport to transfer the CSRF token to the browser and browser can request new CSRF tokens knowing only session id. My point is that hashed CSRF token provides all the security the session id can provide. For example, CSRF token with value `hmac_sha1(session_id, server_static_secret)` is totally okay, assuming that attacker does not know `session_id` (and if he does, he can acquire valid CSRF token from the server).